# Nothing appears when writing to remote X server from the Pycharm Python Console

Tags: python, pycharm, console, x11

I'm doing a robotics project with a Raspberry Pi, developing on a separate PC, and I'd like to display visualisations on the PC, while running in Pycharm Python console to make debugging and extending the program easier.

I've created an SSH tunnel to do X11 forwarding - this works for normal running, but once I tick **Execution -> Run with Python console**, nothing appears the PC when it should.

- No errors or exceptions appear - there's just no output.
- I have `DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` set in the Environment variables box for
  both the Run Configuration and the Python Console Settings
- Running from a different python console (ie. typing `python3` in an SSH shell session) works as expected.

Any idea how I can fix this, or at least start to debug it? I suspect the issue is with how Pycharm starts the remote console session, not sure if some features get disabled or sandboxed in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this, but I've no idea why the fix worked.

Before:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This would run correctly, no exceptions, but wouldn't produce any output on my local system.

Then I changed the pyplot import/alias line so it's now:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

And then it started working!

If anyone can explain why this would make a difference (remember the old code works fine in a normal console, just not in the PyCharm Console) I'd love to know.

As part of my investigation into this, I thought it was something a lower level, so found this failing test:

```
>>> from tkinter import Tk
>>> window = Tk()
>>> window.mainloop()
```

In a normal console the window appears after the `Tk()` call, in the PyCharm Console it appears after the `mainloop()` call. Not sure if this is even remotely related.